# How to get interface names from kernel using pyroute2 IPDB function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to fetch the interface names (like eth0..etc) which exist in kernel using pyroute2 and IPDB functions.

```
import pyroute2

ipdb=pyroute2.IPDB()
   print ipdb.interfaces
```

The above code is displaying full information. But I would need only the  interfaces names.

Desired Output as:

eth0
eth1
...

I don't want to use IPRoute() function to fetch. I want to use IPDB to fetch the information.

Comment: Do you mean the output of ```ipdb.interfaces.keys()```?

Comment: Thanks.. This is what i am looking for.  But ipdb.interfaces.keys is displaying output as [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'lo', 'eth0',  'eno3', 'vethf7', 575, 'virbr1-nic', 'virbr0']. Is there a way which i can fetch only names with out unwanted numbers..

Comment: The numbered are the same interfaces as the named ones. I don't know why IPDB implements it that way. You can see the correspondent names with ```ipdb.interfaces[0].ifname```, for example. Maybe something like this can workaround ```for i in range(len(ipdb.interfaces)/2): print ipdb.interfaces[i].ifname```.

Comment: This seems to do the trick: ```print [ ipdb.interfaces[x].ifname for x in range(1, len(ipdb.interfaces)/2 + 1) ]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pyroute2

ipr = pyroute2.IPRoute()
for link in ipr.get_links():
    print(link.get_attr('IFLA_IFNAME'))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to fetch the interface names using below snippet.

```
with pyroute2.IPDB() as ipdb:
        print(" ".join(ipdb.by_name.keys()))
```

Comment: It is surely a better way. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick:

```
import pyroute2    
ipdb = pyroute2.IPDB()
print [ ipdb.interfaces[x].ifname for x in range(1, len(ipdb.interfaces)/2 + 1) ]
```

I don't like the way pyroute2 implements most of the things but, unfortunately, I'm too new on Python to change that module in way I would like.

Answer (score 1):

just have a look here :

you'll be able to introspect your local network resources .. that's what I'm using on a large systems

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces